# How Convert String to datetime in android

Tags: android, datetime

I trying to convert string to date.
My String like  **20130526160000** .
i want date like dd MMM yyyy hh:mm

e.g.-26 May 2013 16:00

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Is that a date long? Create a Date obj with it and format it using SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` for parsing String to Date.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
try {
  Date d = sdf.parse("20130526160000");
} catch (ParseException ex) {
  Log.v("Exception", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Now you can convert your `Date` object back to String in your required format as below.

```
sdf.applyPattern("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm");
System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
```

Comment: WHat is this Prime.class?

Answer (score 26):

You can use the following way.

```
String strDate = "2013-05-15T10:00:00-0700";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Output is : `Wed May 15 10:00:00 IST 2013`
I hope this will help you.

Comment: How can i get the output like - "15-05-2015" and stored into date variable and when i toast the date then it must show the output ; "15-05-2015"

Answer (score 5):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");  
    Date date=null;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse("20130526160000 ");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"); 

    System.out.println("Date :" +formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: output - Date :26 May 2013 16:00

Comment: Thanks, its work like a charm for my case

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code to parse string to date..

```
java.util.Date date=null;


        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("20130526160000");

            System.out.println(date);// result will 'Sat Jan 26 16:00:00 IST 2013'

            //now you can use Date class function i.e.

            //date.getDay();
            //date.getMonth();
            //date.getYear();



        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(">>>>>"+"date parsing exception");
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think this will helps you.

```
   long _date = Long.parseLong("20130526160000");
 SimpleDateFormat _dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm");
 System.out.println("Date is:" + _dateformat.format(new Date(_date)));
```